# Playing song using service class

Tags: android, android-service

I've been working for this but couldn't get success. I want this codes to convert in Service so that my application can run in foreground. Any help would be very much appreciated. I`m newbie in android and I need this to works immediately.

I have (1) SongsManager.java where I access songs from sdCard and put it on ArrayList>. (2) PlayListActivity.java where I put all songs in ListView from SongsManager.java and when I click an item, it will go to the (3)HirouMusic.java and it will pass the songIndex data from PlayListActicity that will trigger what song index to play.

Here are my codes.

(1) SongsManager.java

```
public class SongsManager {

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,     String>>();

public SongsManager(){

}


public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(Context c) {

final Cursor mCursor = c.getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
                    ,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST
                    ,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
                    ,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID
                    ,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
                    ,MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE }
                    , null
                    , null,
                    "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");


String songs_name = "";
String song_artist= "";
String song_duration= "";
String song_album_id= "";
String mAudioPath = "";

/* run through all the columns we got back and save the data we need into the arraylist for our listview*/
if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {

    String file_type = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE));


        songs_name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
        song_artist = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
        song_duration = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
        song_album_id= mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
        mAudioPath = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();

        song.put("songTitle", songs_name);
        song.put("songArtist", song_artist);
        song.put("songDuration",song_duration);
        song.put("songAlbumId", song_album_id);
        song.put("songPath", mAudioPath);

        songsList.add(song);

    } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
}   

mCursor.close();
return songsList;
 }   
 }
```

(2) PlaListActivity.java

```
public class PlayListActivity extends ListActivity {

// Songs list
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,                   String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,     String>>();

SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
// get all songs from sdcard
this.songsList = plm.getPlayList(this);

// looping through playlist
for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

    // adding HashList to ArrayList
    songsListData.add(song);
}

// Adding menuItems to ListView
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
        R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle","songArtist"}, new int[] {
                R.id.songTitle, R.id.songArtis });

setListAdapter(adapter);


// selecting single ListView item
ListView lv = getListView();
// listening to single listitem click
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // getting listitem index
        int songIndex = position;

        // Starting new intent
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                HirouMusic.class);

        // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
        in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);

        setResult(100, in);

        // Closing PlayListView
        finish();

    }
});

}
}
```

(3) HirouMusic.java

```
public class HirouMusic extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener,
SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,         String>>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

setContentView(R.layout.player);

btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
songAlbum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songAlbum);
songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);
details =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDetails);
songAlbumArt = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.songAlbumArt);

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    songManager = new SongsManager();
    utils = new Utilities();

    // Listeners
    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

    // Getting all songs list
    songsList = songManager.getPlayList(this);

    // By default play first song
    //playSong(0);


btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check for already playing
            if(mp.isPlaying()){

                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.pause();

                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                }
            }else{
                // Resume song
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.start();
                    // Changing button image to pause button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                }
            }

        }
    });

btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(isShuffle){
                Random rand = new Random();
                currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
                playSong(currentSongIndex);
            }
            else{
                        // check if next song is there or not
                    if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                        playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                        currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                    }else{
                        // play first song
                        playSong(0);
                        currentSongIndex = 0;
                        }   
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Back button click event
     * Plays previous song by currentSongIndex - 1
     * */
btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(currentSongIndex > 0){
                playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
            }else{
                // play last song
                playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
            }

        }
    });


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == 100) { 
    currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
    // play selected song
    playSong(currentSongIndex);
}


} // end

/**
 * Function to play a song
 * */
public void  playSong(int songIndex){
// Play song
try {
    mp.reset();
    mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
    // Displaying Song title
    String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
    songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);
    String songAlbum2 = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songArtist");
    songAlbum.setText(songAlbum2);

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

// check for repeat is ON or OFF
if(isRepeat){
    // repeat is on play same song again
    playSong(currentSongIndex);
} else if(isShuffle){
    // shuffle is on - play a random song
    Random rand = new Random();
    currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
    playSong(currentSongIndex);
} else{
    // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
    if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
        playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
        currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
    }else{
        // play first song
        playSong(0);
        currentSongIndex = 0;
    }
}
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList4(Context resolver){


    Cursor cursor = resolver.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
            new String [] {"ARTIST", "DURATION", "TITLE", "_DATA", "ALBUM"}, null, null, null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();

    song.put("artist", cursor.getString(0));

    song.put("duration", cursor.getString(1));

    song.put("songTitle", cursor.getString(2));

    song.put("songPath",cursor.getString(3));

    song.put("album",cursor.getString(4));

    // Adding each song to SongList

    songsList.add(song);

    }

    return songsList;

}
```